# How to Explore Folder directly from Flash Builder?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, flash-builder, contextmenu, right-click, windows-explorer

In FlashDevelop, you can easily open up an Explorer window by right-clicking the particular folder you want to take a look at.

[image]

Unfortunately, I "have" to use Flash Builder for a particular project / company, and I can't seem to find this functionality in the context menu:

[image]

Is there a Flash Builder or Eclipse plugin I can install that would insert a new Context-Menu entry with this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [ExploreFS](http://junginger.biz/eclipse/) plugin for this.

One gotcha is that it doesn't show up if you click on a package in the Package Explorer.  You can work around that by either using the Navigator view or by clicking on a source file in the package in question.

[image: Image demonstrating ExploreFS and the "Explore in File System" context menu entry]

Comment: Cool! I much prefer the Navigator over the Package Explorer anyways, that'll work for me :) Thanks